# Emacs org-mode: how to disable visual line wrap for Agenda buffers only?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, linebreaks

I've activated visual line mode in Emacs with 
`M-x global-visual-line-mode` .

However (only) in Agenda buffers I'd like to autamatically use `truncate long lines` instead.

How can I enable that? Do I have to modify the agenda commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hook is a list of functions ran on particular occasion. Most modes, if not all, have at least one hook, generally named `<mode-name>-mode-hook`, to which you can add functions with `add-hook` and remove functions with `remove-hook`.

You can see if a hook exists and inspect its value with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`<mode-name>-mode-hook`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

In your case, you want to configure `org-agenda-mode-hook`.

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (visual-line-mode -1)
            (toggle-truncate-lines 1)))
```